# How to show video ( in external player) inside a div by javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am using an external player to display a video. but when i append it in a div it just shows [object Object]
I have extracted the video by this function in javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">function loadArchiveInPlayer(vdo) {
var s12 = new SWFObject('http://jetpitch.com/hdflvplayer/hdplayer.swf','player','513','285','9');
    s12.addParam('allowfullscreen','true');
    s12.addParam('allowscriptaccess','always');
    s12.addParam('wmode','transparent');
    s12.addVariable('file',vdo);    enter code here
    s12.addVariable('Preview','<?php echo SITEROOT; ?>/images/video-load-img.jpg');
    s12.write('mediaspace');

    //document.getElementById("newimg1").appendChild(s12);

    return s12;
} </script>
```

After returning the video it is displayed by this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> var s22 = loadArchiveInPlayer(vdo);
document.getElementById('newimg1').innerHTML = s22; </script>
```

But the div "newimg1" dosent displays the video. Please Help.

Comment: Looking at their [docs](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation), it does not look like it supports what you want to do. Seems like they use `document.write()` to output it to the page.

Comment: According to the comment above mine, you could try making an `iframe` instead of a `div`, targetting a local *php/html* file which could be your video player.
Edit: Cancelled a -1 on the question, since no one dared telling us why they voted this down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
s12.write('mediaspace');
```

does the embedding of the flash player into your websites DOM. It adds the flash object into a HTML element with `id="mediaspace"`. Just make sure that you have a div with such an ID in your document.